# how to generate builtin model permissions for non-managed models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have model like this:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'venue'
        permissions = [
            ('change_venue', 'Can change venue'),
        ]
```

It is not managed because it already exists in the database (which was created before django project).

I want to use django's builtin model permissions, but they are not created by default. I tried to add them by changing `Meta.permissions` field but got an error: `The permission codenamed 'change_venue' clashes with a builtin permission for model 'events.Venue'`

What should I do? Just make migration and create permissions manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by creating permissions in `App.ready` hook:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        create_permissions(self)
```

Don't know if this counts as valid solution tho

## Edit 1

Method above didn't work for new database because models "were not ready/create" when app is ready. So I switched to `post_migrate` signal, and everything was fine.

## Edit 2

After some time I have found global problem about why I don't have permissions and content types in the first place: I simply didn't make migrations for un-managed models. With migrations everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar problem, yet even after getting migration script for unmanaged models no new permissions where created. Turns out [permissions are created](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) by `django.contrib.auth` at `post_migrate` signal. Signal is triggered in the end of each migration but most importantly this signal is executed **only** if `models` module is present. So:

1. Make sure you have `migrations` folder in your app then run `python manage.py makemigrations` this should create `0001_initial.py` with the list of your models.
2. Create the `models` folder in your app and import all your models in the `__init__.py` file, as per [these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package):

```
from admin.device.model import Device
from admin.document.model import Document
...
```

3. Run the `python manage.py migrate` command